# Input/output error while executing cp command

Tags: command-line, mount

I'm new in Linux

I'm trying to follow a steps for install ROS on UDOO and I have the next problem.

When I try to download and unpack ubuntu 13.04 i have the next problems:

the command line is:

```
babil0nia@ubuntu:/mnt/sdcard$ wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz tar xzf ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz
```

and returns:

```
--2014-03-24 01:05:08--  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz
Resolving cdimage.ubuntu.com (cdimage.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.92.164, 2001:67c:1360:8c01::20
Connecting to cdimage.ubuntu.com (cdimage.ubuntu.com)|91.189.92.164|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 35939978 (34M) [application/x-gzip]
ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz: Input/output error

Cannot write to `ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz' (Input/output error).
--2014-03-24 01:05:11--  http://tar/
Resolving tar (tar)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `tar'
--2014-03-24 01:05:21--  http://xzf/
Resolving xzf (xzf)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `xzf'
--2014-03-24 01:05:31--  http://ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz/
Resolving ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz (ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz'
babil0nia@ubuntu:/mnt/sdcard$ cd 
babil0nia@ubuntu:~$ cp u
u-boot-q.imx                         ubuntu-core-13.04-core-i386.tar.gz   
ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz  uImage                               
babil0nia@ubuntu:~$ cp u
u-boot-q.imx                         ubuntu-core-13.04-core-i386.tar.gz   
ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz  uImage                               
babil0nia@ubuntu:~$ cp ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz /mnt/sdcard/
cp: cannot create regular file `/mnt/sdcard/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz': Input/output error
```

So I download the ubuntu 13.04 and tried to copy in the /mnt/sdcard/ folder but I have the next problem:

```
babil0nia@ubuntu:~$ cp ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz /mnt/sdcard/
cp: cannot create regular file `/mnt/sdcard/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz': Input/output error
```

Please help what can I do?

first I create an ext3 partion on the sd card whit Gparted

then flash u-boot on the boot sector:

```
dd if=u-boot-q.imx of=/dev/sdb1 bs=512 seek=2 skip=2
```

when i tried flash u-boot i need the command `sudo chmod 777`  for /dev/sd1

then mount the sd card to a local folder

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sdcard
sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/sdcard
```

Comment: Please check your sdcard is properly mounted on `/mnt` folder.

Comment: Post the output of `ls /mnt/sdcard` command.

Comment: Don't give the `wget` and `tar` commands on a single line like `babil0nia@ubuntu:/mnt/sdcard$ wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz tar xzf ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz`

Comment: You have to seperate these two commands as  `wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-core-13.04-c‌​ore-armhf.tar.gz` and `tar xzf ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz`

Comment: And how exactly did you mount your `/mnt/sdcard`? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/438422/edit) your question and add info.

Comment: Have you have solved the problem (and answered sdcard mount issue in question)? All is ok now?

Answer (score 3):

Separate the 2 commands. On separate lines or with a ; or with &&. Need to be in a writable directory to run them.

Let's just get and unpack in $HOME dir for now. cd with no args will change to homedir.

```
cd 
wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz
tar -xzf ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz
```

Or:

```
cd && wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz && tar -xzf ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz
```

**Next part of problem. Writing to sdcard mount.**

Maybe it is mounted so that only root user can write to it.
So try:

```
cd /mnt/sdcard
sudo touch TEST # will prompt for your password
ls -al
```

Do you get an error when you do touch command? Maybe it is not writable by *any* user if so.

So now if you successfully (hopefully, maybe) can write to /mnt/sdcard do:

```
cd /mnt/sdcard
sudo wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzf ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz
```

Or better skip the wget if you already did wget in your $HOME dir. Do:

```
cd /mnt/sdcard
# ~ is shorthand for your $HOME dir
sudo tar -xzf ~/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz
```

Sorry too detailed but hope you can do that and root can write to sdcard. . . If you get errors please post them and the ls -al result of or in /mnt/sdcard. The mount options can be changed to mount it as writable if needed . . . Will require another part of answer!

Comment: I did with the commands separeted and have the same problem and with the && the same problem :/

Comment: babil0nia@ubuntu:/mnt/sdcard$ wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz && tar -xzf ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz


(More terminal messages)

Cannot write to `ubuntu-core-13.04-core-armhf.tar.gz' (Input/output error).

Comment: You are in /mnt/sdcard and cannot write files there. Because of how it is mounted I suppose. Do the wget in another directory to see it working and get the file.

Comment: The error info you posted in comment helps show what problem is. I think problem can be solved by just adding sudo in front of commands. Answer updated.